# Efficient top K PostgreSQL

Tags: python, algorithm, postgresql, sorting, heap

I have a huge table in PostgreSQL and I need to get top K elements.
Is there a way to select Top K entries in O(N logK)?
Most obvious example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY col
LIMIT k
```

will give us O(N logN) solution similar to

```
sorted(arr)[:k] # in python
```

is there a SQL way to do it using heaps?
like in this example:

```
from heapq import nsmallest
nsmallest(k, arr)
```

which is O(N logK) using min heaps?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to express this in PostgreSQL. However, if you create an INDEX on col beforehand then you will get the ORDER BY basically for free yielding a runtime of only O(k). This of course only makes sense if you have a lot of queries of the same form containing col.

Comment: The problem is that there is floating col and we can add any number of rows (we can add rows that will have a values lower or higher then current min/max element)

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand. You can create indexes (e.g, a btree) on columns with float (numeric) values. When you insert new rows, then the index will take care of the ordering (with the drawback of slightly higher insert cost).

Answer (score -1):

Creating an index (e.g., a btree) on the column beforehand will speed up the ORDER BY on that column significantly. You will get some overhead, during insertion, but this will pay off if you have a lot of queries of the same form on the specified column. I found interesting information/experiments on exactly the query you are asking for on [this page](https://madusudanan.com/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-sorting-in-postgres/) (under "Using indexes for sorting")